# Conditionally add object to array

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to conditionally add an object to an array

I have this code:

```
module "r53_records" {
  for_each = var.s3_static_websites[terraform.workspace]
  source   = "terraform-aws-modules/route53/aws//modules/records"
  version  = "~> 2.0"

  zone_name = each.value.zone

  records = [
    {
      name    = each.value.sub_domain
      type    = "CNAME"
      records = [module.cdn[each.key].cloudfront_distribution_domain_name]
      ttl     = 300
    },

    // Only add this object if each.value.create_wild_card == true
    {
      name    = "*"
      type    = "CNAME"
      records = [module.cdn[each.key].cloudfront_distribution_domain_name]
      ttl     = 300
    }
  ]
}
```

I don't see a method I can use to onlyadd the wildcard route53 record based upon a value in the foreach

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically we need to dynamically construct the elements of the `records` module parameter value. We want one mandatory element with one optional element. Therefore, we need to approach this by `concat` one constant `list(object)` with an optional `list(object)` based on a ternary conditional with your specified logic:

```
records = concat(
  [{
    name    = each.value.sub_domain
    type    = "CNAME"
    records = [module.cdn[each.key].cloudfront_distribution_domain_name]
    ttl     = 300
  }],
  each.value.create_wild_card == true ?
  [{
    name    = "*"
    type    = "CNAME"
    records = [module.cdn[each.key].cloudfront_distribution_domain_name]
    ttl     = 300
  }]
  : []
)
```